# Getting TextField Text to Second Class

Tags: java, mysql, swing

I am searching for a `Customer` by his `Name`. The `Name` is in `TextField`. 
Button Gets the Text in TextField And Checks in DB. The Button's Function is as follows:

```
Connection con=null;
 PreparedStatement st =null;
  ResultSet rs =null;        
     try{
       Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); 
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/holt","root","");
        st=con.prepareStatement("select * from customers where Name=?" );
        String Customername = jTextField1.getText();
        st.setString(1, Customername);
        rs =st.executeQuery();

       if(rs.next()){

           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Customer Found With ID = " +  rs.getString("ID") );
           StartSearchByName2 SB =new StartSearchByName2();
           SB.setVisible(true);
           close();

       }
           else{
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Customer Does Not Exist");
          }

  }catch (Exception ex){
        System.out.println("Error "+ex);

     }
```

I want to get the `Name` that the user entered in the `StartSearchByName2` class.

I am trying to use this, but it returns me `NULL`:

```
public class StartSearchByName2 extends javax.swing.JFrame {
/**
 * Creates new form StartSearchByName2
 */
public StartSearchByName2() {
    initComponents();
     StartSByName SB = new StartSByName();
      String cn = SB.jTextField1.getText();
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,cn);  
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: TextField is Public , and there is no error but String cn remains null.

Comment: Your JTextField's text is `null` which makes me wonder **when** you're trying to extract the text. You don't show us, but likely it is near when the JTextField has been created and not after the GUI has been displayed and the user has added information to it. If so, the key here is to extract the text from within some event such as an ActionListener. For better help, please improve your question including showing us **when** you are extracting this information above.

Comment: Please look at the [help] as well as [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to find out how you can improve this question and increase your odds of getting decent answers.

Comment: Also you state "second class". This class isn't **inheriting** from the GUI class, is it?

Comment: Please don't post code in comments since it loses its formatting making it unreadable. Instead, post any new code to the bottom of your original question by [editing your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29954982/edit).

Comment: Sorry for Mistakes, i am new to this online help. 
Thank You.

Comment: i have 2 JFRAMES one for Searching Customer one for Further work. 
I need to get the Name of the Customer User Entered in 1st JFrame to Second JFrame. 
So that i can use same name for further functions.

Comment: My assumption above is correct. You're trying to extract the text before the GUI has been displayed, before the user has had a chance to enter data.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was Able to Solve this problem by just using Static String for customer Name. 
Then Later when i call this string in second class, i will get the last updated value of this string.

Comment: This is not a good solution and is in fact a fragile kludge since your use of static means that your code now no longer is OOP compliant, and this can haunt you when you later want to extend or enhance this program.

Answer (score 2):

Yep, my assumption was correct: you're getting your JTextField's text near when the JTextField has been created and not after the GUI has been displayed and the user has added information to it. If so, the key here is to extract the text from within some event such as an ActionListener. Give the GUI a JButton, say called submitButton, add an ActionListener to the JButton and in the listener get your text.